# SQL-using CASE in SELECT returns only first case value

Tags: sql

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT Policy_type_ID,Policy_Value Value,CASE Policy_Value WHEN max(Policy_Value) THEN 'Highest' WHEN min(Policy_Value) THEN 'Lowest' END AS Range
FROM Policy_Types
GROUP BY Policy_type_ID,Policy_Value
HAVING ((Policy_Value IN (SELECT max(Policy_Value)
FROM Policy_Types)) OR (Policy_Value IN(SELECT min(Policy_Value)
FROM Policy_Types)));
```

But the result has only one value 'Highest' in the column 'Range'.Its only regarding the first case,whichever it maybe, and ignoring the rest.

```
Policy_type_ID   Value   Range
501180          990000   Highest
690002          10       Highest
690006          10       Highest
690007          10       Highest
```

I've no idea where I'm going wrong. Its just that CASE statement that is the problem....any help??

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `MAX(Policy_Value)` when `Policy_Value` is one of the columns you're grouping by, since it's computing the max for each group. Within each group, the value is always equal to the max.

Comment: Are you trying to compare this policy value with the maximum across the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `MIN` and `MAX` functions are being calculated within the `GROUP BY` groups, not across the entire table. You need to calculate them in a separate subquery that doesn't have `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Policy_type_ID, Policy_Value, 
       CASE Policy_Value
         WHEN MaxPolicy THEN 'Highest'
         ELSE 'Lowest'
       END Range
FROM Policy_Types
JOIN (SELECT MIN(Policy_Value) MinPolicy, MAX(Policy_Value) MaxPolicy) MinMax
HAVING Policy_Value IN (MinPolicy, MaxPolicy)
```